# Google Analytics not capturing data when parameter list starts with semi-colon (;) instead of question mark (?)

Tags: google-analytics

I'm having an issue with capturing search terms, when the URL/URI parameter list starts with a semi-colon instead of a question mark.

Two sections of the site I'm working on use different delimiters for the search parameter list. One uses the usual question mark (?) to define the start of a parameter list for search terms:

```
example.com/section1/searchwas?destination=Toronto
```

And the other uses a semi-colon (;) to identify the search string:

```
example.com/section2/searchwas;q=blue
```

I get data from the "destination" variable identified as search terms, but nothing from the "q" parameter.

From what I can see, Analytics is ignoring any part of the URL after the semi-colon.

I've tried applying a filter to the site to replace the semicolon

```
search string = ;
replace string = \?
```

but no luck.

I've set up the view to enable search, and defined "destination" and "q" as parameters. I've even tried using ";q" as the search parameter...

```
;q,filter_category_code,destination,q
```

Is anyone familiar with this issue, and know of a solution?

Comment: Hi @Jay - when you say "I've tried applying a filter to the site" do you mean (a) you're applying a filter to the GA view or (b) you are making modifications on the site itself?

Also, how have you implemented GA? Is it straight up on the site or using Google Tag Manager?

Comment: Hi Vinoaj - On the question of the filter, I mean I'm applying a filter to the GA view. We went back and forth on the implementation - this portion of the site is currently tagged in GA, but will eventually be moved to GTM.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. @Jay did you ever figure out a solution?

Comment: Hi @KevinLeStarge -- No, it seems like there's no simple solution. Either recode the site so that the URLs use the question mark; or try to push out the code provided in the answer through Google Tag Manager - we haven't tried either yet.

Comment: I ended up recoding the routing of the site to use traditional query params instead ot the matrix notation (;) style. What a pain! At least GA is picking up my parameters now :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that the search processing is happening before the filter is applied on the hit. The method to overcome this is to rewrite the URL before the hit is sent to the Google Analytics collection servers.

One way to do this would be:

```js
var newPath = document.location.pathname.replace(";","?");
// ...
// ...
ga('set', 'page', newPath);
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

Comment: ... and replace subsequent ";" to &... that actually was how it worked for me on an angular site, such noise